# :last-child pseudo-class mixed with attribute selector not working

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to select the first and last child of an element with a specific `data-` attribute.

The `:first-child` selector works fine, but `:last-child` isn't working. I seriously don't know what can cause this. I have checked for typos.

CSS

```
.element[data-type='element']:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;   
    background-color:red !important
}

.element[data-type='element']:last-child {
    padding-right: 0; 
    border-right:0; 
    background-color:red !important;
}
```

Comment: Depending on the rest of your HTML structure, you might have better luck with [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) and [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type).

Comment: You need to put a semi-colon after `!important` in your **first-child** selector. It's not affecting that selector (as it's the last rule) but it could be affecting the next.

Comment: No luck. I changed :first and :last child to :first-of-type and :last-of-type but its still the same issue. I also added the semicolon, but that didnt fix it.

Comment: @worldofjr: It should not affect the next rule.

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/x4w1t21e/). As such we can't debug it with the given info

Comment: Heres what i have. http://codepen.io/Jarolin/pen/wKmfp Maybe its the HTML structure. Any ideas?

Comment: @UserDy That's because the ones after the first three don't have the same `data-PB-element-type` :) Therefore you can't select the last one because while it is the `last-child` of the parent, it does not have the matching data type. There currently is not `last-of-class` selector (or `last-of-data-type` equivalent)

Comment: Or the last one matching any arbitrary condition you could think of.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I'm trying to select the first and last child of an element with a specific `data-` attribute.

Bottom line is, there's no way to do that in CSS.

`last-child` (and `last-of-type`) mean, well, "last child", and "last child of type", they do **not** mean "last child matching the entire selector including an attribute selector". In your case, it is likely that the third `div` is not actually the last child (or not the last `div`) within the parent element; it's impossible to tell unless you show the entire HTML including the parent element and all its children.

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me with

```
.element:first-child[data-type='element'] {
```