# :last-of-type doesn't work

Tags: html, css

[image: Example GIF]

I have a HTML document with the abbreviated HTML content:

```
<div class="list">
    <form name="signupForm">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input>
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input>
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input>
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input>
      </label>
      <label class="item item-button">
        <input class="button button-block button-positive">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-button">
        <input class="button button-block button-signup">
      </label>
    </form>
</div>
```

My expected behavior is that the CSS selector `.item.item-input:last-of-type` will grab the 4th `label` element and the last `.item.item-input` element of the `form` parent.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you're doing wrong is misunderstanding `last-of-type`. Search harder for answers here on SO, there are several. `last-of-type` refers to **last element of its type (tag) within that parent**. It doesn't know or care about what other selectors you may have combined, such as `.item-input`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924535/last-child-pseudo-class-mixed-with-attribute-selector-not-working.

Comment: the gif is great~!! it presents the problem so clear! How did you do it?

Comment: I was having a similar issue where `:last-of-type` was not working as I was expecting. Using `:not(:first-of-type)` did the trick for me though. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`:last-of-type` matches an element which is the last element of its type (tag) within its (first-level) parent, period. It doesn't know or care about what other selectors you may have combined, including class selectors such as `.item-input`, or anything else.

There is no straightforward way in CSS to accomplish what you want, which could be expressed as `:last-of-selector`. Some alternatives that have been suggested include

1. Wrap the first four elements in a separate div, so you can do `:last-of-type` within it.
2. Have somebody (server, local JS) mark the element you want with a specific class, and refer to it.
3. Other hacks, such as hard-wiring the number of extra elements at the end that you want to skip, and use `:nth-last-of-type`.
4. Give the elements in question a different tag, if you can so manage, and then you can use `last-of-type`.

Comment: To be more precise, last-of-type is button-signup. And will be the same, no matter what selectors do you write

Comment: the key in this answer for me is: within its 1st level parent. And I tried to use the css class name rather than tag name, it still works. So if the class you'd like to select isn't in the 1st level, just include the class names between the parent class and your target class name, it will work :). In my case: ```.parent .middle-class-name .target-class:last-of-type ```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently [`:last-of-type`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#last-of-type-pseudo) (from the MDN Docs) can only be used with namespace and [type selectors](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-3/#type-selectors) (tag name selectors like `input`).

I suggest changing your HTML structure to wrap the `.item-input` elements in a `<div>`. Alternatively, I have also seen a `.last` class manually added to substitute the pseudo-selector.

Comment: Confirmed. `.item.item-input` does not work but `.list label` does.

Still looking for a solution! Otherwise I'm going to have to do some weird `.list label:nth-of-type()` stuff.

Comment: @Ian Yes, I think you will have to change your HTML structure.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by saying "can only be used with...type selectors". Do you mean that `.item.item-input:last-of-type` is invalid?

Answer (score 1):

Finding the `.class:last-of-type` is not possible. The `:last-of-type` CSS pseudo-class represents the last sibling with the given **element name** in the list of children of its parent element. The correct syntax is `element:last-of-type`

You might be interested in `:nth-last-of-type(n)`, you could then use the following selector to target that element.

```
label:nth-last-of-type(3) { style properties }
```

The `:nth-last-of-type(n)` selector matches every element that is the nth child, of a particular type, of its parent, counting from the last child.

However, you'll need to use Javascript if you can't edit the markup and the number of items isn't fixed.

Comment: This is what I'm doing so far, but it assumes I have a fixed number of items from the bottom. Which is true now, but may not always be true in the future.